# How can I Highlight links only in Blog Posts with Mouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I want to Highlight all Links that Appear on a Post Article in my Blog. I Tried a few CSS codes but they worked all over the Blog.

I need to Apply it Only on Blog's Post Links and not on the Whole Page.
How Should I Do This?

I Dont have much Knowledge of CSS And My Blog is Hosted on Blogger. Please Help

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add css on .post-content a. pretty much depends on the theme you are using. a link to your blog would be helpfull

Comment: Sorry Bro, But i am Not Able to Understand You. I am very much weak in HTML and Stuffs. I Would rather appreciate if you could elaborate

Comment: please paste your site source and it woukd be more clear.or link to the website

Comment: so you should use .post_wrapper2 a { color:blue; } in your template

Comment: I need a Mousehover effect. This Didnt Work.. Sorry Bro

Comment: then add .post_wrapper2 a:hover { color:blue } or whatever highlights you have :)

Comment: just did it with firebug. added: .post-wrapper a { background:yellow } then added .headline_meta a { background:none } and .post-title.entry-title > a { background:none } . this way, only links inside the post get yellow background, the meta information and the title stay the same

Comment: Thanks Bro. Used the Following Code. But Still links outside the blogpage are getting highlighted

Comment: a { 
color:#f00; 
background:transparent; 
text-decoration:none; 
} 
a:hover { 
color:#fff; 
background:#1BC5F0; 
text-decoration:underline; 
} 
.headline_meta a { background:none }
.post-title.entry-title > a { background:none }

Answer (score 0):

In Blogger, for the posts headings there is a class name `title`. So, you can do the following to mention the highlighting only for the post titles.

*Please check the class name of the post title using your favourite browser's developer tool.*

```
.title a
{
   //css style for highlighting
}
```

Comment: I Dont want to HighLight Post Title. That is already done in the Template. I just want to highlight the links in the article like you can see in "http://www.shoutmeloud.com/google-webmaster-tool-search-queries-improve-blog-conversion.html"

Comment: @ReshamPanth link is broken.